# API Testing tools in C#

Tags: automated-testing, c#, visualstudio, api

I'm looking at writing at automated tests to cover regression testing in respect of Restful API's.

I have familiarity with how to do this in Java using Rest Assured, however the company I currently work for is a **.NET** house so it would make sense to write the automated tests **in Visual Studio using c#** as the programming language.

My question is whether anyone has any advice on testing tools that can be utilized, or point me in the direction of how I might go about building a framework in **C#**. Essentially, coming at this from the ground up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API test automation: GUI tool vs programmatic approach?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29613/api-test-automation-gui-tool-vs-programmatic-approach)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the combination of any unit testing framework (like NUnit, MSTest, XUnit) with additional nuget packages for the work with REST API itself

- RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/) Probably the most popular and convenient REST HTTP Client for .Net.
- RestAssured.Net (https://github.com/lamchakchan/RestAssured.Net) .Net port of Java's lib, may be easier for you if you are already familiar with this approach.

Also I recommend using the Json.NET (https://www.newtonsoft.com/) nuget for convenient work with the request/response JSON data, it's much easier to work with the deserialized objects that with the plain JSON strings.

Answer (score 6):

Writing an API test in Visual Studio can be done with:

- NUnit or MSTest as your Test Runner
  ** NUnit and the TestAdapter are available on Nuget
- An http client, like .Net's HttpClient
  ** This is in the System.Net namespace
- (Optional) Json.Net for parsing responses
  ** Also avaiable on Nuget

Your test will look something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Record01StatusCode()
{
    // Arrange: Define the endpoint to be tested
    string requestUri = "http://foo.bar/record/01";
    // Act: Make the request (Note: MakeRequest is a method I wrote in another class)
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.MakeRequest(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
    // Assert: The request returns a successful response
    Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode, "Response was not a success status code!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

- this http://unirest.io/net
- or this http://restsharp.org/
- or this https://github.com/lamchakchan/RestAssured.Net

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jmeter or Postman to test the APIs. It will be easy to form the payload . If further to automate can invoke Jmeter through Jenkins, command line or batch file.